# nvidia-smi gives an error inside of a docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia-docker

- Sometimes I can't communicate with my Nvidia GPUs inside a docker container when I came back to my workplace from home, even though the previously launched process that utilizes GPUs is running well. The running process (training a neural network via Pytorch) is not affected by the disconnection but I cannot launch a new process.
- `nvidia-smi` gives `Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error` and `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False` likewise.
- I met two different cases:
- 1. `nvidia-smi` works fine when it is done at the host machine. In this case, the situation can be solved by restarting the docker container via `docker stop $MYCONTAINER` followed by `docker start $MYCONTAINER` at the host machine.
- 2. `nvidia-smi` doesn't work at the host machine nor `nvcc --version`, throwing `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch` and `Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` error. Strange point is that the current process still runs well. In this case, installing the driver again or rebooting the machine solves the problem.
- However, these solutions require stopping all current processes. It would be unavailable when I should not stop the current process.

Does somebody has suggestion for solving this situation?

Many thanks.

(sofwares)

- Docker version: 20.10.14, build a224086
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Nvidia driver version: 510.73.05
- CUDA version: 11.6

(hardwares)

- Supermicro server
- Nvidia A5000 * 8

---

- (pic1) nvidia-smi not working inside of a docker container, but worked well on the host machine.
  [image]
- (pic2) nvidia-smi works after restarting a docker container, which is the case 1 I mentioned above
  [image]

---

Additionally,

- `Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error` is reproducible by calling `systemctl daemon-reload` at the host machine after starting a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem of `Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error` and having to restart the container, please see this ticket and post your system/package information there as well:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1671

There's a workaround on the ticket, but it would be good to have others post their configuration to help fix the issue.

> Downgrading containerd.io to 1.6.6 works as long as you specify no-cgroups = true in /etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml and specify the devices to docker run like docker run --gpus all --device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 --device /dev/nvidia-modeset:/dev/nvidia-modeset --device /dev/nvidia-uvm:/dev/nvidia-uvm --device /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools:/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools --device /dev/nvidiactl:/dev/nvinvidiactl --rm -it nvidia/cuda:11.4.2-base-ubuntu18.04 bash

so `sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades containerd.io=1.6.6-1` and `sudo apt-mark hold containerd.io` to prevent the package from being updated. So do that, edit the config file, and pass all of the `/dev/nvidia*` devices in to `docker run`.

For the `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch` issue, that is caused by the drivers updating but you haven't rebooted yet. If this is a production machine, I would also hold the driver package to stop that from auto-updating as well. You should be able to figure out the package name from something like `sudo dpkg --get-selections "*nvidia*"`

Comment: I'll try your solution for the first case. In the `Driver/library version mismatch` error case, I believe I'd solved the problem by preventing unattended updates in the Ubuntu system. Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

Need to install appropriate version of [NVIDIA drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us),
recommend drivers could be found through following command.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Inappropriate versions of drivers might cause multiple issues as mentioned below, even if we might able to forward gpu instance to container, cuda projects might not work.

After installing docker, we followed [this guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html) to forward GPU instance from host to container.

Comment: I exactly followed installation guide of `docker` and `nvidia-docker`. My driver version is `525.60.11`, which I searched via official Nvidia website. I suppose this problem is less related to the version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who's suffering from the same problem, this is the solution I found and my machine works fine for about 2 years. Note that this solution requires re-creation of a docker container.

1. Check your problem is identical to mine. You can check this (not sure if its perfectly identical) via executing `systemctl daemon-reload` at the host side while your docker container in running. The Nvidia driver will not respond inside of your container after this.
2. Create a new docker conatiner. Pass all instances under `/dev`. Example: `--device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 --device /dev/nvidia1:/dev/nvidia1 --device /dev/nvidia2:/dev/nvidia2 --device /dev/nvidia3:/dev/nvidia3 --device /dev/nvidia4:/dev/nvidia4 --device /dev/nvidia5:/dev/nvidia5 --device /dev/nvidia6:/dev/nvidia6 --device /dev/nvidia7:/dev/nvidia7 --device /dev/nvidia-caps/ --device /dev/nvidiactl --device /dev/nvidia-modeset --device /dev/nvidia-uvm --device /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools`
3. Check if the problem is solved. Run `systemctl daemon-reload` at the host side and check `nvidia-smi` works fine inside of the container.